# How to create authorization transaction using braintree api's?

Tags: paypal, braintree

I'm using the sdk of the braintree in golang for doing payments. I want to authorize the card before the transaction. Then I have read some link which tell me that if I pass the `status:AUTHORIZED` then the transaction will be authorized I make a sample code for this and it response me the same the status will be authorize but on the braintree dashboard-> home page on the bottom there is total amount will be displayed it will be increased with the amount I'm passing in the request. What it means? 1. "Transaction success" or 2. "Authorize success". I also check the summary of the transaction when I reached on the single transaction page then the transaction status is authorized and there is only the button of the "void" payment. I also click on that button then the amount will be deducted from the home page total amount.

Please tell me that What it mean? If someone having the problem to understand please post a comment. Sorry I have written this case as I did.

Sample code:

```
func transaction() {
bt := braintree.New(braintree.Sandbox, "merchId", "pubKey", "privKey")
ctx := context.Background()
customer := &braintree.CustomerRequest{
    FirstName: "abc",
    LastName:  "def",
    Email:     "abc@gmail.com",
}
btCust, err := bt.Customer().Create(ctx, customer)

cardObj := &braintree.PaymentMethodRequest{
    CustomerId:         btCust.Id,
    PaymentMethodNonce: "fake-valid-visa-nonce",
}
cardData, err := bt.PaymentMethod().Create(ctx, cardObj)

txnObj := &braintree.TransactionRequest{
    Type:               "sale",
    PaymentMethodToken: cardData.GetToken(),
    Amount:             braintree.NewDecimal(1000, 2),
}
tx, err := bt.Transaction().Create(ctx, txnObj)
fmt.Println(tx.Id, tx.Status) // 12234 authorize
fmt.Println(err) // nil
}
```

Code reference from the sdk: https://github.com/braintree-go/braintree-go

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have further questions, contact [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

A transaction with a status of [Authorized](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/transaction-lifecycle#authorized) means the customer's card-issuing bank has initially approved a transaction. However, funds are only collected from the bank if you submit the transaction for settlement. You can confirm this by seeing the transaction is in a [Submitted for Settlement](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/transaction-lifecycle#authorized) status.

When you click the Void button in the Control Panel, you are telling the customer's bank that you want to reverse the transaction. I recommend reading more about the transaction lifecycle linked above and further about [Refunds, Credits, and Voids](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/refunds-voids-credits).